# How to make marker image in google maps to blink

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am having some markers on maps

the part of the code is here

```
var icons=["media/green.png","media/red.png","media/blue.png","media/yellow.png"];

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(100*array_lat[j],100*array_lon[j]),
            map     : map,
            url     : "javascript:setNavtrack('DISPLAYDATA')",
            icon    : icons[i]
           });
```

As my wish i want to blink the "media/red.png" icon

Any solution?

Comment: Blinking markers? What is this, 1997?

Comment: mblase give a solution..

Comment: I couldn't live with myself for taking points in order to make the Internet even uglier than it already is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try changing media/red.png for a "blinking" media/red.gif and if it doesnt work, change marker.optimized to false: (code from [.gif marker google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979676/gif-marker-google-maps) answer)

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    icon: iconoMarca,
    optimized: false
  });
```

To look like:

```
var icons=["media/green.png","media/red.gif","media/blue.png","media/yellow.png"];
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(100*array_lat[j],100*array_lon[j]),
            map     : map,
            url     : "javascript:setNavtrack('DISPLAYDATA')",
            icon    : icons[i],
            optimized:false
           });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: mapOptions.center
    });

    interval = setInterval(function() { toggleMarker() }, 500);

    function toggleMarker() {
      if (marker.getVisible()) {
        marker.setVisible(false);
      } else {
        marker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an animated gif, that blinks.

Comment: You could use imagemagick to morph between the marker and an empty image: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#morph

Comment: You could use imagemagick to do so: `convert -size 100x100 xc:white -alpha Transparent canvas_white.png` should work. See: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid
Or you could just use any Imaging Program like GIMP to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get animated gifs looking good, so I tried a different approach based on this demo on YouTube of “[Localmind](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoihGhqyfAE)”. It turned out pretty good.
Here's the section of code I used to make it work. Note that I'm using some wrappers and utilities, so you'll have to do some translation or removal of sections.

```
// setup the selection state that is needed
var circle,
    intervalWaitCount = 10,
    startingStrokeWeight = 1,
    circleOptions = {
        radius: 0, // in meters
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: red,
        strokeWeight: startingStrokeWeight,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
        center: marker.position
    };
// remove from the last selected
if (components.MapWrapper.lastSelectedMarker) {
    components.MapWrapper.lastSelectedMarker.circle.setVisible(false);
    window.clearInterval(components.MapWrapper.lastSelectedMarker.interval);
}
if (marker.circle) {
    marker.circle.setVisible(!marker.circle.getVisible());
    circle = marker.circle;
} else {
    circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
    marker.circle = circle;
}
marker.interval = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (intervalWaitCount > 5) {
        intervalWaitCount--;
        return;
    }
    var radius = circle.getRadius();
    circleOptions.strokeColor = green; // choose a color, I was changing based on a condition
    circleOptions.center = marker.position;
    if (radius <= 50000) {
        circleOptions.strokeWeight = circleOptions.strokeWeight - 0.1;
        circleOptions.radius = radius + 10000;
        circle.setOptions(circleOptions);
        // don't wait
        intervalWaitCount = 0;
    } else {
        circleOptions.radius = 0;
        circle.setOptions(circleOptions);
        circleOptions.strokeWeight = startingStrokeWeight;
        // wait five cycles before restarting the animation
        intervalWaitCount = 10;
    }
}, 100);
components.MapWrapper.lastSelectedMarker = marker;
```