# Reset blinking marker in googlemap

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I manage to blink my marker using this code

```
interval = setInterval(function() { toggleMarker() }, 500);

function toggleMarker() {
  if (marker.getVisible()) {
    marker.setVisible(false);
  } else {
    marker.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

from here [How to make marker image in google maps to blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740754/how-to-make-marker-image-in-google-maps-to-blink)

Now I need to unblink the marker, tried this and other combination not working

```
   function unblinkMarker(marker){
   if (marker.getVisible()) {
    marker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the interval timer with a `clearInterval()` call:

```
function unblinkMarker( marker ) {
    clearInterval( interval );
    interval = null;
    marker.setVisible( true );
}
```

Also, you can simplify this line of code:

```
interval = setInterval(function() { toggleMarker() }, 500);
```

to:

```
interval = setInterval( toggleMarker, 500 );
```

and it would be a good idea to clear the interval timer before setting it, just in case you'd already set it before:

```
clearInterval( interval );
interval = setInterval( toggleMarker, 500 );
```

This assumes you have a `var interval;` somewhere globally to all these functions.