# Display .gif image marker in google maps V3

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Google Maps V2 supported all gif image markers to display in map. Now I'm migrating from V2 to gwt-maps-3.8.0 where .gif markers are displaying as constant markers. I found some similar questions but I didnt got exact thing which i'm looking for.

```java
 String iconName = "Fire.gif";
 MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions.create();
 markerOptions.setDraggable(true);
 MarkerImage image = MarkerImage.create(iconName);
 Marker marker = Marker.create(markerOptions);
 marker.setPosition(LatLng.create(30.440099, 36.843498));
 marker.setMap(map);`
```

Note: I need GWT code for Google Maps V3. Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use animated .gif images, see this post [.gif marker google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979676/gif-marker-google-maps/5979869#5979869)

I don't know GWT, but this should work with the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

```
marker.setOptions({optimized: false});
```

Comment: Please check GWT code here... http://ameenit.blogspot.in/2013/02/display-gif-images-marker-in-google.html