# Is google map marker image supports .gif format in googlemap?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

In my android application I need to create an animation effect to my marker. I tried it using some code but the animation disappear while we zoom out the map. Is it possible to use .gif image as Google map marker,if not please tell me a proper solution for this.

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: but it is not android code

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The reference is for JS, we don't have v3 for Android yet. Even if we did, I doubt they will support.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874324/display-gif-image-marker-in-google-maps-v3