# Using gif as a marker in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, animated-gif

I am using [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to cluster my marker . By using it I am customizing my markers by using following code

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyMarker item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptorMan = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_man);
    BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptorWoman = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_woman);
    BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptorBoy = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_boy);
    BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptorGirl = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_girl);

    if(item.getResultset().getGender()==null) {
        markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptorMan);
    } else {
        if (item.getResultset().getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("female"))
            markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptorWoman);
        else
            markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptorMan);
    }

    markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
}
```

What I want to do is to use gif image as a marker , so that I could blink my marker . How can I do it ?

I have seen several example of SO but didn't find any solution while clustering marker on android .

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715920/gif-type-animation-for-marker-in-google-map-api-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715920/gif-type-animation-for-marker-in-google-map-api-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display .gif image marker in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874324/display-gif-image-marker-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: @Sanoop Yes I checked this , but they are not adding marker as cluster item

Comment: @SiKing The link you mentioned isn't related to android

Comment: Did you find a solution?