# Customizing Markers in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google map and I want to customize the Icon

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
```

I want to show the marker something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoihGhqyfAE
have the surrounding wave effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons), or the examples in it?  What problems did you run into?

Comment: Yes i have gone through the document and created the marker although i am not satisfied with that, i need some thing like as show in the video  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoihGhqyfAE having the effect around the marker

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only animations that can be applied to a marker are 'BOUNCE' and 'DROP'. However, you can get your marker to look like the one in the video by creating an animated gif.
1) Create the animated image of the marker using image editing tools
2) add the image into your project
3) set the marker icon to your image

You may need to set the the marker property to 'optimized' to 'false'. Here is a different question to that should help you once you create the animate image you want to use: [.gif marker google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979676/gif-marker-google-maps)

Comment: I want to know whether this feature can be achieved by using some other maps or j query